# Add common CSS to all the elements having same attribute

Tags: html, css

I have a table section as below. I want that wherever I have "col" attribute a margin of 20px should be added on the left. I just need help with the syntax for this.

I have edited the question and included my complete code here. Please note that in the mobile view each row is stacked on top another.

```
<div class="tableComponent">   
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Designation</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      
      <td col="Name">Mark</td>
      <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
      <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tableComponent table{
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size:12px;
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.tableComponent table thead th{
  
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.tableComponent table td,th{
  border-top: 0px;
}


.tableComponent .table-striped tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#F8F8F8 
 }

 .tableComponent tr{
    border: hidden;
    
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px){

    .tableComponent table{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5vw
    }

    .tableComponent  thead {
        display: none;
      }
      
    .tableComponent  tr {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        
      }
      
      .tableComponent td::before {
        content: attr(col);
        font-weight: bold;
        
      }

      .tableComponent td[col]{
        padding-right: 5rem;
      }

     
      
}
```

I don't know how to write this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remember that when using ::after you need the rule: `content: '';`

Comment: This new code has totally changed the problem. What exactly is it that you are trying to do - add space inside the cells? And in which media query? Also, there is space showing on the right in both media queries so I'm not clear what the problem is?

Comment: In mobile view. I just need space between the title and the data i.e. between Name and name value, & so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the `td` with `col` attribute, you can do it like this:

```
td[col]{ }
```

But note that `margin-right` won't work on the td - you have to use padding.

When you are dealing with tables, you can't apply the same spacing in the same way as you can for other elements, For example:

- you can't add margin to a table cell
- you can't add different sized borders between cells

Working Snippet using padding:

```css
td[col]{
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

---

**UPDATE**: Your edit totally changed the question so the above answer no longer helps.

The problem now is that you are adding the padding in the wrong place. You are adding the title outside the table structure by using `:before`, so when you try to add padding to the cell itself, it isn't getting added where you want it.

This is your CSS and it is correct, except that your titles are not in a cell so it is not adding the padding to them:

```
 .tableComponent td[col]{
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
```

Instead, you need to add the padding in the CSS rule that styles the title, e.g.

```
  .tableComponent td::before {
    content: attr(col);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
```

**Working Snippet** (Note I've increased the media query to 5000px so we can see it here):

```css
.tableComponent table{
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size:12px;
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.tableComponent table thead th{
  
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.tableComponent table td,th{
  border-top: 0px;
}


.tableComponent .table-striped tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#F8F8F8 
 }

 .tableComponent tr{
    border: hidden;
    
}


@media all and (max-width: 5000px){  

    .tableComponent table{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5vw
    }

    .tableComponent  thead {
        display: none;
      }
      
    .tableComponent  tr {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        
      }
      
      .tableComponent td::before {
        content: attr(col);
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-right: 10px;
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="tableComponent">   
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Designation</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      
      <td col="Name">Mark</td>
      <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
      <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td col="Name">Mark</td>
        <td col="Designation">Otto</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

To select the cells with specific `col` values, you can do this:

```
.tableComponent td[col="Name"]::before {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.tableComponent td[col="Designation"]::before {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

To make all the titles the same width, you can do this:

```
.tableComponent td::before {
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: hi.I tried this but didn't reflect in my code. I have edited the question and included the actual code. Could please tell me what am I missing out here?

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta Your new question is a totally different problem! It uses flex layout and padding, not td and margins. If you have a different question, you should add it as a new post. Each question on Stack Overflow should be about one specific problem (and not change problem half way through :) )

Comment: Yes. But I still need to access the attribute. I just need the syntax. Could you please help out?

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta I've shown you how to access the attribute, and you can see it working in the snippet. See my comment on your question - what you want is unclear so we can't help out until we know exactly what you want.

Comment: In mobile view. I just need space between the title and the data i.e. between Name and name value, & so forth.

Comment: Thank you ! It solved the problem. I had been trying wrong styles within the same block all this time! If I need to access single class, for example just the [col]="name" then how do I have to do that?

Comment: Thanks a ton !! It is clear to me now. I just have one quick question as I am not able to find any answer to that. I am trying to keep my code as neat as possible. Now, if we apply common padding to all the titles it does not format title values one below another because obviously the titles are not of equal length due to which we add different spacing in each case. I just wanted to know if there is a direct command to format the text in css ? I have 3 columns as example now. But if I have say 10 cols,  writing separately for each entry would lead to too many lines of code.

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta I'm not really sure what you mean, but I think you might be looking to make the titles all the same width? I've added one more example to my answer. If that's not what you wanted, I can't help, sorry!

Comment: thank you for all your time and effort and providing such detailed solutions. I really appreciate. Thanks man !

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta *Wo*man, not man :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to select all cells with *col* attribute:

```
td[col]{
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

If you want to select cells with col equals to "Name", you can do this:

```
td[col="Name"]{
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta That's because you can't apply margin to table cells, see my answer below

Comment: Try with padding rather than margin, or use `border-collapse: separate`

Comment: yes. i already that. please check the updated code in the question.

Comment: If you want a margin on the left, then you have to use `padding-left` instead of `padding-right`